# Packages Pynput and Pyautogui not working

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui, macos-big-sur, pynput

I'm trying to automate some stuff on my Mac OS Big Sur 11.5.2 . I used to do it on my old computer that was running High Sierra. Now both the packages `pyautogui` and `pynput` can run but they never execute the commands that they're supposed to. It's also strange as when I try to `pipinstall pynput` I get this:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
    pyobjc-framework-ApplicationServices>=8.0; sys_platform == "darwin"
    (from pynput) (from versions: 3.1, 3.1.1, 3.2, 3.2.1b1, 3.2.1, 4.0b1, 4.0, 4.0.1, 4.1,
                   4.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 5.0a1, 5.0b1, 5.0, 5.1, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.2, 5.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyobjc-framework-ApplicationServices>=8.0;
    sys_platform == "darwin" (from pynput)
```

However when I try to run it using `pip3 install` it says `Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-core>=8.1 in`.

Online it seems to say that I need to downgrade my `pyobjc` to 7.3, but it's really not clear on how to do that.